# Forward all ports to single machine on NETGEAR WPN824v2

Tags: router, port-forwarding, netgear

Using my NETGEAR WPN824v2, I would like to **forward all ports to a single machine**. However, when I try to add a single forwarding entry to an otherwise empty forwarding list, it complains that there is a conflict, but then seems to end up with a corrupted forwarding table internally (at least I am observing some of the mapped ports not being forwarded at all).

What is the correct way to forward all ports? Is it even possible? I realize it might not be advisable to do so, and instead list all ports explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a setting called "Exposed Host" or "DMZ Host"; you should be able to use that to tell the router to forward all otherwise unconfigured ports to the specified machine.

Comment: Found the setting and verified that it works as you describe. Thanks!